# Want to display image in the circle it is possible and how

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

hi i want to display image in the circle not in the rectangle and all this will display in the tableview
[image: show image like that in tableview cell]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and add a cornerRadius to your imageView
`[yourImageView.layer setCornerRadius:yourImageView.frame.size.width/2]` maybe you have to add `[yourImageView setClipsToBounds:YES]`, but i am not sure about this.

Comment: thanks it works for me but tell me one thing i am also displaying videos in webview then the same thing will work for it as you said

Comment: Just for others help, [yourImageView setClipsToBounds:YES] is Mandatory

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to create a subclass of NSView.

Then in you override drawrect: methods to do your custom drawing. You start by drawing your image in your defined frame. After that, you can either draw over, in the the same frame, an image of a rectangle with a transparent circle in the middle or use NSBezierPath to construct a similar rectangle.

The color of this rectangle, except the transparent circle in the middle, is the same as the background color of the enclosing view.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `-drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f); //size of image frame
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:aRectangle];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIColor *imageColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
    [imageColor setFill];
    [path fill];
}
```

First of all you need to create your own class inherited from UIView (for example) and put this code into your `drawRect`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the image as a PNG and add a transparency layer. Select the area around the circle and make it transparent. Then when the image is loaded in the UIImageView, it will appear as just a circle.

For example:

[image: table view with two rows and circle images]

Comment: It's about a programmatically solution not about setting images.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to use [CICircularWrap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICircularWrap) . It wraps an image around a transparent circle.

For example like this:

[image]

then u can use **UIImageView's layer setCornerRadius** to perfect circular image